# Looking for Connection Ideas for 12V Battery Pack

Tags: batteries, electrical

I'm working on a project that's requiring the use of a battery pack made from 18650s. 3 of them in series connected to a BMS. It's a 12V supply that is housed in a 3D printed part, length wise of the batteries, like a hot dog. I haven't had much luck in trying to find a terminals similar to what might be seen on a laptop battery, camera batteries, etc. When searching all I can seem to find are either car battery terminals, or the basic ring or spade terminals you'd find in an assortment kit.

Originally, I was using a DC female/male jack, but do to space limitations I'm not going to be able to fit that in the design. If I can charge/discharge through a single port, great. If not, I figure I'll need wire something similar to a portable phone charger's layout.

Any ideas on what to use or any resources where I could browse these types of connections? The smaller the better.

Answer (score 0):

Remote control hobby equipment uses various connectors, my favorite is the XT-60 for the power. For balancing the cells, most seem to agree on a JST-HX connector (yours will need to be 4 pinned). You might consider using the same interfacing hardware.

The beauty of copying an existing "standard" is that you can easily use hobby grade chargers (a lot of inexpensive but excellent choices out there).

Comment: Wasn't aware of the JST-HX connector. Will look into those, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try an R/C hobby site. They use that kind of cell a lot, even packaged together with the protection circuit.